# What .cpp to put code in on qt form

Tags: c++, qt

Ok so I am making a GUI program. I made a form called translationForm so it made three files. translationForm.h translationForm.cpp and translationForm.ui and then main.cpp that is created on start up. So if I want to use code that references a radio button on the form. Would I put that code into main.cpp or translationForm.cpp

If translationForm.cpp:
Can I just delete Main.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code that interacts with the radio button into translationForm.cpp.

You need to keep the main file, because it defines the entrance into the program.

If you look at the examples for Qt, they all have a main.cpp, and in each one, it creates QApplication, followed by an instance of the widget or window it will show and then it calls exec on the QApplication variable.

That sets up the Object tree and the Event loop that Qt needs for the GUI's to work.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/object.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html

Here is what your main should look like, but replace widget and Widget with the name of your class.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: by class you would mean translationForm?

Comment: Yes.  That is the name of your class.  If you look in your .h file it says `class TranslationForm` or something similar towards the top followed by `: public QForm` a `{` on the next line.  You can also see the name of your class in your translationForm.cpp... it is the name before all the double colons: `<ClassName>::<ClassName>(QWidget parent)` is the constructor, and `void <ClassName>::function()` is an example of a function added to the class.